# drawing a vertical line in a sympy plot of a piecewise function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I have the following piecewise function defined in a jupyter notebook:

```
from sympy import *
Mt, F1, Fax, Fay, Faz, Fbz, Fby, l, x, alpha, a, b, c, d, e = symbols('Mt, F1, Fax, Fay, Faz, Fbz, Fby, l, x, alpha, a, b, c, d, e')

My1 = 0
My2 = sin(alpha)*F1*(x-a)
My3 = sin(alpha)*F1*(x-a) - Fay*(x-(a+b))
My4 = sin(alpha)*F1*(x-a) - Fay*(x-(a+b))- Fby*(x-(a+b+c))
My5 = 0

My = Piecewise((My1, x<a), (My2, And(a<x, x<b)), (My3, And(b<x, x<c)), (My4, And(c<x, x<d)), (My5, And(d<x, x<e)))

My
```

and try to draw it:

```
params = {alpha: 30, a:0.024, b:0.074, c:0.132, d:0.189, e:0.219, F1:11700, Fay:-8762.57, Fby:26973.41}
plot(My.subs(params), (x, 0, e.subs(params)), title= "Biegemoment $M_y(x)$")
```

with the following result:

[image]

This is basically fine, I would just like to have a vertical line at x=0.074. I tried with `adaptive`and `nb_of_points` mentioned [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html) but it did give an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py in __call__(self, *args)
    118             temp_args = (np.array(a, dtype=np.complex) for a in args)
--> 119             results = self.vector_func(*temp_args)
    120             results = np.ma.masked_where(

...

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2165                       for a in args]
   2166 
-> 2167             outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
   2168 
   2169             if ufunc.nout == 1:

FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in ? (vectorized)
```

Answer (score 1):

The current plotting module is unable to achieve what you would like to do with a single step. There are at least two approaches.

#### First:

Using the current plotting module, create a plot for each piece and combine them together

```
from sympy.plotting import plot

plots = []
for expr, cond in My.subs(params).args:
    cond = cond.as_set().subs({-oo: 0, oo: e.subs(params)})
    plots.append(splot(expr, (x, *cond.args[:-2]), show=False))
# combine all plots together
p = plots[0]
for i in range(1, len(plots)):
    p.extend(plots[i])
# optionally set the same color for each piece
for series in p:
    series.line_color = "b"
p.show()
```

[image]

#### Second:

Pretty much the same thing, but using `lambdify` and matplotlib to achieve full customization.

#### Third:

Install the [Sympy Plotting Backends](https://github.com/Davide-sd/sympy-plot-backends) library. Here, you can either use the `plot` function activating the `detect_poles` algorithm (it detects vertical asymptotes, but it is also good for this case):

```
plot(My.subs(params), (x, 0, e.subs(params)), title= "Biegemoment $M_y(x)$", detect_poles=True, eps=1e-06)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `plot_piecewise`: this is also going to highlight the extremities of the pieces. Filled circle means an extremity is included in the interval (`<=, >=`), empty circles it is excluded (`<, >`).

```
plot_piecewise(My.subs(params), (x, 0, e.subs(params)), title= "Biegemoment $M_y(x)$")
```

[image]